# What's the other way to think about SE2 and SE3? My brain only seems to go one way

Tags: intuition, transformation, isometry

I work at a robotics company and we have littered throughout our code transforms of the form `t_a_b`. I continually think of `t_a_b` as "How do I get from a to b" where `a` and `b` are each a location with a heading.

If I take some global reference frame `g`, then `nalgebra`'s `inv_mul` function is how I find the isometry between two points. I can express `a` as `t_g_a` and `b` as `t_g_b`, and then to get from `a` to `b`, it's just `t_g_a.inv_mul(t_g_b)`. That is, if I know the latitude and longitude of SF, and I know that latitude and longitude of Mountain View, these are each describing `t_(0,0)_SF` and `t_(0,0)_Mountain View`, and then a really, really long way to get from SF to Mountain View would be to first go from SF to the map's origin point (equator x prime meridian) (which is the inverse of going from origin to SF) so that's `t_(0,0)_SF.inv()` and then go from the origin to Mountain View which is multiplying by `t_(0,0)_Mountain View`. Put it all together and I get `t_(0,0)_SF.inv() * t_(0,0)_Mountain View` but for performance and conciseness reasons I write this as `t_(0,0)_SF.inv_mul(t_(0,0)_Mountain View)` = `t_SF_Mountain View`.

Any time I see `t_a_b * t_b_c * t_c_d` in the code, this translates to me as "First go from a to b, then go from b to c, then go from c to d" so this is equivalent to the "rigid body transform" which takes you from a to d.

This has worked great for me and not caused any issues at all. It agrees with the way that everybody else writes code... Until I found out that one of my coworkers insists that I'm thinking about everything backwards. *Definitely* `t_a_b` means the exact opposite of what I think. When you want to get something something reference frame something `a`, you start at `b` and then apply the function which is multiplying `t_a_b` by `pt_b`.

No matter how hard I try, this makes absolutely no geometric sense to me, but for all my Googling and ChatGPTing, 30% of the time I'm right and my coworker's wrong and 70% of the time he's right and I'm wrong (but there definitely are a few sources that see it my way too). Somehow our code is able to interact with each other and not fall over and somehow our naming conventions agree with each other, but I *just* *can't see what he's talking about*. It sounds like utter gibberish. And the 70% of academic sources that agree with him also sound like gibberish.

I refuse to accept that I'm totally incapable of understanding this other conception of how SE3 transforms work. Can somebody *please* help me bridge this conceptual gap? (It may be telling that I've mostly worked on motion while he's mostly worked on perception. Also, my introduction to programming was with turtle graphics when I was 9 years old. Multiplying isometries just seems like sequencing instructions in turtle graphics)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your code, let me take a guess at what your issue probably is.  Misunderstandings of this sort are usually caused by disagreement on one of the following two issues:

(1) Are transformations *active* (objects move) or *passive* (coordinate systems / cameras move)?

(2) In a product of transformations $AB$, which is performed first, $A$ or $B$?

If two people disagree about exactly one of (1), (2), then their code will be incompatible, but if they disagree about *both*, then their code will be compatible again.  This is because an active transformation described by a matrix $A$ is equivalent to a passive transformation described by $A^{-1}$.  Since $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, taking inverses *and* reversing the order makes things compatible again.

Instead of *active* and *passive*, some sources use the terms *alibi* and *alias*. An active transformation moves the object *to another place* (alibi), while a passive transformation moves the coordinate system, giving the object new coordinates, i.e., *another name* (alias).

Does this help?

Comment: No, I was looking for something concrete; not just a general principal of dual forms. Someone on the Math Discord clarified it for me. In my model (of eg. SE2), the point moving around the grid has a _heading_ and when it _rotates_, it keeps the same coordinates but changes only its heading (like a turtle in turtle graphics). In the standard model that my coworker uses, points have no heading, and rotations are always applied _about the origin_, not about the point. Translations are with respect to the global orientation, not with respect to the turtle's orientation.